# How to handle windows Form in seleniuim

Tags: winforms, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where i am getting a windows form ,AutoIT is not able to handle this window form,is there  some other way to handle window form using selenium

Comment: clarify more ....

Comment: are u want to switch frm one window to another

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to automate OS level dialogue boxes/windows forms with **AutoIT**, you can use **Sikuli** to automate your windows forms.

**Sikuli:**
Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.you can get more info from below link-
http://www.sikuli.org/
http://www.devengineering.com/blog/testing/how-integrate-sikuli-script-selenium-webdriver